# Send commands to Context Broker using iotagent-ul

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to send commands to the Orion Context Broker using iotagent-ul with HTTP protcol.
Context Broker and IoT Agent are in different servers (actually IoTA is in running in my laptop).
I've configured the necessary parameters in `config.js` file.

My request is as follows:

```
curl -L POST -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ 
"devices": [ 
    { 
        "device_id": "sensor01", 
        "entity_name": "LivingRoomSensor", 
        "entity_type": "multiSensor", 
        "attributes": [ 
              { "object_id": "t", "name": "Temperature", "type": "celsius" },
              { "object_id": "l", "name": "Luminosity", "type": "lumens" }                  
        ]
    }
] 
}
' 'http://localhost:4061/iot/devices'
```

It shows the following erros:

- In IoTA terminal:

`time=2017-02-14T15:06:14.832Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=88ed3729-6682-44ce-9b0a-28098e54c94e | trans=88ed3729-6682-44ce-9b0a-28098e54c94e | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | srv=myHome | subsrv=/environment | msg=TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined | comp=IoTAgent`

- In "cURL terminal":

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Answer (score 0):

Please can you tell us what's the IoT Agent UL version you are using?

On the other hand, it seems you are missing the 'protocol' field in the payload, please check

http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection-to-the-internet-of-things/how-to-read-measures-captured-from-iot-devices/

best

Comment: Thanks for your answer José Manuel.
I created a device properly but I can't send measures to Orion using IoT Agent Ultra Light.
Could you help me?

Comment: please can you describe precisely what is happening?

Comment: Hi José Manuel,

I've solved it. I don't know what exactly I did.
Now I have another problem, that I show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281731/device-group-not-found-in-iotagent-ul).