# DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND in iotagent-ul

Tags: fiware

I'm trying to send measurements using IoT Agent UL2.0.

First, I created a device as follows:

```
POST /iot/devices HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4061
Fiware-Service: Empresa1
Fiware-ServicePath: /empresa1
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{ 
"devices": [ 
    { 
        "device_id": "A6", 
        "entity_name": "A6", 
        "entity_type": "E6", 
        "attributes": [ 
              { "object_id": "a", "name": "aaa", "type": "text" },
              { "object_id": "b", "name": "bbb", "type": "text" },
              { "object_id": "c", "name": "ccc", "type": "text" }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Then I'm trying to send measurements as follows:

```
POST /iot/d?i=A6&amp;k=A6&amp;d=a|7|b|7|c|7 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7896
Fiware-Service: Empresa1
Fiware-ServicePath: /empresa1
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "name": "DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "Couldn\t find device group"
}
```

What the `device group` is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to solve it.

I just changed `config.defaultTransport` to `HTTP` in `config.js` and used `TEF` as apikey.

The request that effectively sent measures to Orion was the following:

```
POST /iot/d?i=A6&k=TEF&d=a|7|b|7|c|7 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7896
Fiware-Service: Empresa1
Fiware-ServicePath: /empresa1
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

be careful, you need to configure a service, so that you can use your own API KEY, and that can be done by issuing an HTTP request like this

```
    POST http://130.206.80.40:5371/iot/services

    Headers:

    {
      'Content-Type':       'application/json',
      'X-Auth-Token' :      '[TOKEN]',
      'Fiware-Service':     'openiot',
      'Fiware-ServicePath': '/'
    }

    Payload:

    {
      "services": [
        {
          "apikey":      "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
          "cbroker":     "http://0.0.0.0:1026",
          "entity_type": "thing",
          "resource":    "/iot/d"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer from jose-manuel-cantera is correct. Also, pay attention in the `resource` field should start with a slash `/`. I was having the same issue as yours, see this ticket https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/issues/459.